# Not able to draw bubble chart with PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, charts, phpspreadsheet

Trying to draw simple bubble chart with PhpSpreadsheet but got only the data without the chart. Here is my code:

```php
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Chart as ExcelChart;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\DataSeries;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\DataSeriesValues;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Layout;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\PlotArea;
    
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Category');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Value 1');
    $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Value 2');
    $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Bubble Size');
        
    // Sample data
    $data = [
      ['Category 1', 10, 20, 30],
      ['Category 2', 15, 25, 40],
      ['Category 3', 20, 30, 50],
    ];
    foreach ($data as $rowIndex => $rowData) {
      $rowNumber = $rowIndex + 2;
      $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $rowNumber, $rowData[0]);
      $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $rowNumber, $rowData[1]);
      $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $rowNumber, $rowData[2]);
      $sheet->setCellValue('D' . $rowNumber, $rowData[3]);
    }
    $chart = new ExcelChart(
      'BubbleChart', // name
      null, // title
      null, // legend
      null, // xAxisLabel
      null, // yAxisLabel
      null // layout
    );
    $dataSeriesLabels = [
      new DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$1', null, 1), // Category labels
    ];
    $xValues = [
      new DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$B$2:$B$4', null, 3), // X-axis values
    ];
    $yValues = [
      new DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$C$2:$C$4', null, 3), // Y-axis values
    ];
    $sizeValues = [
      new DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$D$2:$D$4', null, 3), // Bubble size values
    ];
     
    $dataSeries = new DataSeries(
      DataSeries::TYPE_BUBBLECHART, // plotType
      DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD, // plotGrouping
      range(0, count($xValues) - 1), // plotOrder
      $dataSeriesLabels, // dataSeriesLabels
      $xValues, // xValues
      $yValues, // yValues
      $sizeValues // sizeValues
    );
    
    $layout = new Layout(['layout' => 'blip', 'manualLayout' => ['w' => 300, 'h' => 200, 'x' => 0, 'y' => 0]]);
    $plotArea = new PlotArea($layout, [$dataSeries]);
    $chart->setPlotArea($plotArea);
        
    $sheet->addChart($chart);
    
    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
    $writer->save('php://output');
        
    exit();


Once again: The result in Excel file is: data appears but the chart is missing. What is wrong?
```